# I am able to open URL'http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/' in firefox,but when I run selenium script in eclipse it shows 'The connection has timed out'

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox, testing

I am able to open one URL in firefox, but when I run selenium script for the same in Eclipse it does not get load,it shows as : **"The connection has timed out
The server at www.demo.guru99.com is taking too long to respond. "**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase the timeout to ensure that the objects are available to selenium.
To handle the error, better include this code in @BeforeTest or @BeforeSuite annotation which ensure the entire test suite will not run if this fails.
You can also use try/catch to catch the error and throw exception. Choose whatever is best solution in your case.

you can define separate functions to handle errors like code:

```
public static Boolean IsObjectExists(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        try {
            driver.findElement(locator);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I had tried with....'// driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  ' still it gets timeout

Comment: try with implicitlyWait as mentioned in the script.